# Program to rotate an image using pillow without rotate fuction error

Tags: python, rotation, python-imaging-library

I need to make a program that rotates an image a quarter turn counterclockwise without using the rotate function in python.
I think my program should work, the image is created but there is nothing just a black image.
My code:

```
im = Image.open("smiley.bmp")
im.show()
largeur, hauteur= im.size
px = im.load()
def rotation(image):
  largeur, hauteur= image.size
  new = im.copy()
  if largeur >1:
    moitie = largeur//2
    a = im.crop((0, 0, moitie, moitie)) # en haut à gauche
    b = im.crop((moitie,0,hauteur,moitie))# en haut à droite
    c = im.crop((moitie,moitie,hauteur,hauteur)) # en bas à droite 
    d= im.crop((0,moitie,moitie,hauteur))# en bas à gauche
    #récursif
    rotation(a)
    rotation(b)
    rotation(c)
    rotation(d)
    new.paste(d,(0,0)) #d à la place de a 
    new.paste(a,(moitie,0)) #a à la place de b
    new.paste(b,(moitie,moitie))
    new.paste(c,(0,moitie))
  new.save("smiley1.png")
```

The image will be a square.

[image: Imaged used smiley]

I use pycharm and replit python.

Comment: Please show us the full error you receive, including traceback. "some things block it" isn't useful debugging information.

Comment: @Kemp,The error is not visible on python, it's just that the image is created but there is nothing just a black image.

Comment: Then that is the important information we need. You didn't mention what the actual problem was in your original post.

Comment: @Kemp oh my bad sry, but I don't know what the problem is, that's why.

Comment: One thing I will say is that your cropping will work by coincidence for a square image, but will be completely wrong for anything else. Also, you call the function recursively, but never return anything or modify the input parameter. You just save over the output file over and over again (including once you get down to a single pixel, you just save that pixel as the entire image).

Comment: @Kemp I will add assert to be sure that it is a square but it is normal because the function will be used only on squares and concerning what you said I do not understand too much because I save the image only at the end. Could you make the changes so that I can see my mistake?

Comment: You save the image at the end of the `rotation` function, but that function calls itself many times. Each of those calls will save their little piece of the image. You quarter the image and quarter it and quarter it until you're down to a single pixel and then you unwind the calls saving that final pixel as the image, then replacing that by saving the block of 4 pixels it was taken from as the image, then the block of 16 pixels, and so on, replacing the output file over and over until you get back up to the top level again and do the final save.

Comment: An important issue is that when you call, for example, `rotation(a)` you never actually modify `a` within that call. It becomes the `image` parameter for that call and `image` is never touched other than to find the width and height. You could take out the calls to `rotation(a)`, `rotation(b)`, etc and the code would perform exactly the same task it does now (minus saving to the file many times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would like to use a recursion algorithm to solve the problem, so I modified your code a bit.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("smiley.bmp")
im.show()
largeur, hauteur= im.size
px = im.load()


def my_rotate(image,largeur, hauteur):
  if largeur<2:
    return image
  moitie = largeur//2
  a = image.crop((0, 0, moitie, moitie)) # en haut à gauche 
  b = image.crop((moitie,0,hauteur,moitie))# en haut à droite 
  c = image.crop((moitie,moitie,hauteur,hauteur)) # en bas à droite 
  d = image.crop((0,moitie,moitie,hauteur))# en bas à gauche 

  a = my_rotate(a, moitie, moitie)
  b = my_rotate(b, moitie, moitie)
  c = my_rotate(c, moitie, moitie)
  d = my_rotate(d, moitie, moitie)

  new=image.copy()
  new.paste(d,(0,0)) #d à la place de a 
  new.paste(a,(moitie,0)) #a à la place de b
  new.paste(b,(moitie,moitie))
  new.paste(c,(0,moitie))
  return new


new = im.copy()
new = my_rotate(im, largeur, hauteur)
new.save("smiley1.png")
```